# Is there a way to prevent dgrid tree double-click from expanding a row?

Tags: dojo, dgrid

By default, a dgrid tree expands a row whenever it is double-clicked (I verified this using http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/demos/laboratory/). Is there a way to disable this behavior? In other words, the only way for users to expand a row should be to click the arrow *next* to the folder.

I also sent this question to dojo-interest@mail.dojotoolkit.org

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from a teammate. Add

```
expandOn: ".dgrid-expando-icon:click"
```

when you create the tree. For example:

```
tree({label: "label", field: "field", expandOn: ".dgrid-expando-icon:click"})
```

If expandOn is undefined, then the tree module defines the expand trigger as click, double-click, OR keydown. If we define it specifically to click, then the double-click and keydown triggers are disabled.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in the latest dev branch (0.5 at this time).